# MSMessagesAppViewController messes up UITableViewController scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, imessage-extension

When my MSMessagesAppViewController changes the presentationStyle from `compact` to `expanded` and back to `compact`, my UITableView is messed up regarding its scrolling.

I am using AutoLayout to setup a `UITableView` inside of a View called `contentView`.

```
// Inside MSMessagesAppViewController
func createTableView() {
    let tableViewController = MyTableViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(tableViewController)

    tableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tableViewController.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.contentView.addSubview(tableViewController.tableView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableViewController.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableViewController.tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableViewController.tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableViewController.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
}
```

After expanding and collapsing the MSMessagesAppViewController, I can suddenly scroll past my last cell in the tableView...

Everything is working perfectly fine in the initial state. I noticed, that the scrollbar is visible on startup, but is not present after the size change...

This is how I setup my tableView in the controller:

```
// Inside MyTableViewController
func setupTableView() {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(QuickStandardTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "standardCell")

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear

    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 8.0

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false 
}
```

What I checked:

- The contentView frame changes correctly
- The tableView frame changes correctly
- The contentInset does not change
- The contentSize does not change

Does anybody know what I am missing?

[image: On Startup]

[image: Afterwards]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just noticed, that Dropbox has the exact same issue with their tableView in their iMessage app! Seems to be an iOS bug. I‘ll be opening up a bug report

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside instead of using `UITableViewController`.

I had the same problem with an `UICollectionViewController` and switching to `UIViewController` solved this problem.